# How can I identify and source an old faucet cartridge

Tags: plumbing, faucet, plumbing-fixture, cartridge

I have an old faucet that drips. I would like to fix the leak, but am having a lot of trouble finding a replacement cartridge.

The faucet does not have any markings of any kind. I brought the cartridge in to several hardware stores and dedicated plumbing supply stores, but nobody could identify it. I have also searched [online plumbing supply stores](http://www.amresupply.com/catalog/Cartridges-Stems-PE2G/50/250/), but again no luck.

Normally I would take this as a hint and replace the faucet. But I plan to upgrade the whole bathroom in the near term, so a new faucet seems especially wasteful (it would likely be scrapped again during a renovation).

The broach outside diameter is 7/16" and it has 34 teeth.

Is there a better approach to sourcing a replacement part for this faucet?

[image: faucet]
[image: side]
[image: top]
[image: bottom]

Comment: Have you searched here to see if you can identify the one you need http://www.brasscraft.com/pdf/sp-0341_serviceparts_catalog_stems_by_length.pdf? If you find it, you may want to look over http://www.brasscraft.com, give them a call, and see where you can order or if they see to common resellers or retailer in your area such as Lowes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like an American Standard brand of faucet. Probably same stem as a Hampton (pic below) or Williamsburg style faucet. The part number for that cartidge might be 994053-0070A pictured below. The cheaper version would be Danco 10472 4Z-24H/C Stem for American Standard Faucet. You should try to call American Standard (800 442 1902), and you should try to send them your pictures (above). And read the fine print on the [warranty](http://www.americanstandard-us.com/assets/documents/amstd/other/2CABC983.pdf) from American Standard.

[image: Hampton Style Faucet] [image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've done very thorough footwork & exhausted the market, great job on really trying. I also don't see much of anything that you could rebuild or tighten up.

However, if the plastic can be removed without damaging it. Then, you may find that some items can be removed & replaced by the same pieces from a cheap improper & unrelated replacement, which just has the same diameter.

Conversely, go for "the" or "a" new faucet that fits into your future plan. The primary new faucet consideration being that it comes with an **optional deck plate** to cover the vanity top's holes.

This is what I've done in preparation for my new bath, where I want a single handle & single hole faucet. I found that many single hole faucets include an optional deck plate, which can be omitted later with the reinstall on the new vanity top.

Comment: thanks for the idea to look for a deck plate. The trouble here is getting my wife to decide now on a "future plan" faucet! She'll want to plan out the whole thing so that she can "picture" it :)

Comment: Just get her some nice big HD Google Images...all with single hole faucets of course. Stack the deck to your advantage. To stay on the cheap, I.E., no shots with granite or marble counters (that you can't do in laminate) or no tile everywhere (you want painted walls outside of the shower, enclosed tub & floor) or no stained glass windows & full glass shower walls (you want new, neat, clean & simple "elegance"). That she can screw up with pink & flower wallpaper.