# Identify faucet stem

Tags: faucet, cartridge

My bathroom sink faucet has seized up and needs replacement. It should be a simple swap of a new cartridge.
But I can't figure out the brand! The faucet is likely 20 years old and may be as old as 40 years. The sink itself is labeled Kohler. The ribbed spline on top has 16 ridges.    Yet the exposed cartridge does not look like the common Kohler cartridge type... especially the ribbed top with the two sections. There's no label or printing on the stem.

Any ideas what cartridge this uses? Thanks!
[image: Faucet stem]
[image: Sink itself i]

Comment: I've been having so much trouble sourcing a similarly-old cartridge for a faucet that also looks similar (http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82052/how-can-i-identify-and-source-an-old-faucet-cartridge). Please report back if you find one anywhere.

Comment: Have you searched here to see if you can identify the one you need http://www.brasscraft.com/pdf/sp-0341_serviceparts_catalog_stems_by_length.pdf? If you find it, you may want to look over http://www.brasscraft.com, give them a call, and see where you can order or if they see to common resellers or retailer in your area such as Lowes, etc.

Comment: 1Fish, thanks for that link to the cartridge guide! I had looked for something similar before I posted. My faucet cartridge turned out not to be in it... it may be a custom Kohler variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I haven't seen one like this but the simplest solution would be to turn off the water to it, should be a valve under the sink and remove the valve stem. The first hex nut above the large thread, turn counter clockwise, once out take it to a plumbing supply to match it with a replacement new one and install it to get things working again.

Comment: Richard, your answer is of course the correct one. I was trying to save a step (and hardware store trip) by pre-identification.  It turns out that my cartridge is PROBABLY a Kohler, but it's not common. However, a standard Kohler cartridge fits and works! But it's missing that top extended threaded barrel and double-long stem, so it won't work with the handle screw-on trim... so my sink now has an ugly trimless exposed valve. It's likely that I'll just order brand new sink hardware and redo it all since the local HW store, Home Depot, and Google have not helped me find a swap-in fix.

Comment: It's strange that Home Depot wouldn't have it but like I said I haven't seen one quite like this myself. I had the same issue with my tub faucet and since the handels were metal it was a hell of a job to change them and I'm stuck with clear plastic showing brass through them untill I change the whole thing.  ;) lol lol